# Does Puppet 4 include Code Manager?

Tags: puppet, r10k

I've been reading about using R10K with Puppet to manage my environments with git.

According to [this blog](http://garylarizza.com/blog/2014/08/31/r10k-plus-directory-environments/) some of the functionality of R10K was built into later versions of puppet:

> Because R10k was so popular and widely deployed, an environment
>   solution that was a simple step-up from an R10k deployment was made
>   the target, and directory environments were born.

This led me to question if I should use R10K. So I started reading about the use of [control repos in the Puppet documentation](https://docs.puppet.com/pe/latest/cmgmt_control_repo.html). According to the documentation I can either use R10K or Code Manager:

> If you already have a Puppetfile, you can now configure code
>   management. Code management configuration steps differ, depending on
>   whether you’re using Code Manager (recommended) or r10k.

I had never heard of Code Manager so I went to the [page describing Code Manager](https://docs.puppet.com/pe/latest/code_mgr.html) in the Puppet documentation. According to this page Code Manager uses R10K under the hood.

I'm getting the impression from the documentation that Code Manager is now a built in feature of Puppet? Is this the case or is it something that needs to be installed?

*Note: I'm using the community version of Puppet not enterprise.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code Manager is a PE only feature, it's not built into Puppet.

Code Manager is basically an API that gets triggered when events happen on your Git server.

Example Workflow with Gitlab:

- Someone merges a pull-request into the production branch of the control repo
- Gitlab fires off a JSON payload at the code manager API
- The code manager API reads the payload, sees that it's for the production branch
- Code manager triggers an R10k Run for the production branch

I'm simplifying, as there's other steps (error checking, authentication etc) but that's essentially what's happening.

For open-source users, there's a less featured Code Manager like tool in the r10k repo: https://github.com/voxpupuli/puppet-r10k#webhook-support

[image: Gif]

It works in a similar way, but it's has less features and is not officially supportable. But it's a similar workflow: Sinatra app listens for JSON Payloads, when it receives one it triggers and R10k run for the given branch.